Angular (socket.io-client) cant send/receive message from SpringBoot (netty-socketio)
Angular is connecting on my spring boot app
However it connects/disconnects

This is my angular service
Angular cant send or receive
export class WebsocketService {
isBrowser = false;
socket:any;
public message$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
constructor(
@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
) {
this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)
if (this.isBrowser) {
 try{
   this.socket = io("ws://ipV4here:8081?room=chatRoom123",{})
   console.log(this.socket)
 }catch (e){
   console.error(e)
 }
}
console.log( this.isBrowser)
}
sendMessage(message: any) {
if (this.isBrowser && this.socket) {
  this.socket.emit('send_message', message); 
  console.log(message)
} else {
  console.error('WebSocket connection not available');
}
}
getNewMessage ():Observable<any> {
if (this.isBrowser && this.socket) {
 console.log("receiving: ")
 this.socket.on('get_message', (message: any) =>{
   console.log(message)

   this.message$.next(message);
 });
}
else {
 console.error('WebSocket connection not available');
}
return this.message$.asObservable();
};
}

This is my class SocketIOModule
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SocketIOModule {
private final SocketIOServer server;
private final SocketIOService socketService;
public SocketIOModule(SocketIOServer server, SocketIOService socketService) {
    this.server = server;
    this.socketService = socketService;
    server.addConnectListener(onConnected());
    server.addDisconnectListener(onDisconnected());
    server.addEventListener("send_message", Message.class, onChatReceived());
}
private DataListener<Message> onChatReceived() {
    return (senderClient, data, ackSender) -> {
        log.info(data.toString());
        service.sendMessage(data.getRoom(),"get_message", senderClient,data.getMessage());
    };
}
private ConnectListener onConnected() {
    return (client) -> {
        final String roomVariable = client.getHandshakeData().getSingleUrlParam("room");
        final String room = Objects.nonNull(roomVariable)?roomVariable:"temp";
        System.out.println(room);
        client.joinRoom(room);
        log.info("Socket ID[{}]  Connected to socket", client.getSessionId().toString());
    };

}
private DisconnectListener onDisconnected() {
    return client -> {
        log.info("Client[{}] - Disconnected from socket", client.getSessionId().toString());
    };
}

}

When i test it on postman backend receives the message so infer that the angular must be the one that have errors on it

send or receive data from angular
